# TabLayout - multiline tab title with icon

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

On the tab I need an icon and a one or two-line text depending on its length. As long as I don't have an icon everything works as expected. Titles that fit in one line are displayed in one line, and titles that don't take two lines. When I add an icon, the text starts being forced into one line (not to mention it is clipped on the left side). See comparision image below:

[image]

Can i achieve the multiline text effect when an icon is present without creating a custom tab layout?

My code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabInlineLabel="true"
        app:tabMaxWidth="150dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
    tab.text = "Long text which takes multiple lines"
    tab.icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.ic_add)
}.attach()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom `View` for your tab item:

1. Create the layout `View` for you custom tab item.
2. Inflate, bind data, and set this custom `View` to your tab:

   ```
   TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab, position ->
       val tabItemLayout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_tab_item, null).apply {
           findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.tab_icon_imageView).setImageSource(R.drawable.ic_add)
           findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tab_title_imageView).text = "Long text which takes multiple lines"
       }

       tab.customView = tabItemLayout 
   }.attach()
   ```

Comment: The question was whether I can achieve it without creating a custom layout. I have a working workaround with a custom layout already :)

Comment: @suue Sorry, my bad. But it seems like no other way...